# google youtube api query character issue

Tags: javascript, google-api

In the Node.js application while sending request to google api if `q=Ağrı Dağı` response was called as bad request but if i change query to `q=Agri Dagi` it is working. But in the browser if i enter url like this;

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Ağrı Dağı&type=video&key=blabla
```

in spite of using turkish character(ağrı dağı) this url calls json objects successfully in the browser .

Is this issue about node.js request module ? or Should i send queries non-turkish characters everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [encodeURIComponent(yourComponentHere)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode strings for use in URLs.

UTF8 characters are not allowed in URLs and need to be encoded. Your browser does this as well, but it hides it from you so you can still read the URL.

Comment: Thank you bro , it is so important.